# Put JSON response value into new array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop, array-push

I’m trying to use the Yelp API. In order to get the information I need, I first need to call the Yelp Search API, extract the IDs of the venues, and the use the IDs to call the Yelp Business API to drill down to the info I need.

As I’m doing quite a few of these API calls I’m using curl_multi and so I need to send in my data in an array. I have the first call to the Yelp Search API and I am able to see the IDs being returned. However, I am then trying to put those IDs into a new array to use in the second curl_multi to the Yelp Business API. I’m trying to use array_push but I just can’t get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
    (EDIT)//A for loop to get the first 20 results   
    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    // $results contains this search results as an associative array
    $results = reset(json_decode(curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]), true));

    //I set up 2 arrays, the $idArray to use in the 2nd API call and $testNull
    $idArray = array();
    $testNull = array();

   //the JSON response is decoded previously and here I go through the first 20 results
    for($j = 0; $j < 20; $j++){
        //Here I put the ID of each venue into $busID
        $busID = $results[$j]['id'];
        //In case the result is null I have set up this if statement
        if(!empty($busID)){
            //This is echoing out the IDs of the venues correctly    
            echo $busID;
            //and here the problem lies - just can't get the IDs in $idArray
            array_push($idArray, $busID);
            }else{
                //I set this up just to test NUll responses from the 1st API call.
                array_push($testNull, $busID);
            }
    }
}
    var_dump($idArray);
    var_dump($testNull);
```

As I said in my comments, echoing $busID does indeed give me the IDs from the 1st Yelp API call, but var_dump of $idArray just returns an array with 20 NULL values.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Comment: Instead do `$idArray[] = $busID`

Comment: Thanks Erevald, I have tried that already but it won't work either unfortunately.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me...https://3v4l.org/kb95I

Comment: Anything after this would just be a guess as the code you provided appears to work just fine. I'm going to go out on a limb and ask, is this code wrapped in a function or something and having an issue with function scope? PHP doesn't share variables defined inside of a function with those defined outside. Meaning that by default, a variable modified in a function isn't changed outside of said function.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jonathan, this code is indeed wrapped in a function however there's no variable I'm trying to use from outside so scope isn't an issue. There is one thing though...this for loop is inside another for loop. Might be easier to edit my original post to show what I mean...

Comment: why u need to use `reset()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside another loop, you will still see the vardumps.  This section of code works...see this sandbox link:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ddc4084713ae8ac15783ac653466524556b4169a

But inside another loop, your $idArray may be being reset to empty.

Comment: Thanks WEBjuju, when I removed the declaring of the arrays from the outer  for loop it did indeed, work!

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that your `$idArray` object is created on each new 'iteration'. Perhaps the last iteration has null values ? and `var_dump` only prints the last array object (after the loops have finished) - since the dump is outside the loop

Move your arrays:

```
$idArray = array();
$testNull = array();
```

On top of the loop so:

```
$idArray = array();
$testNull = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do now...Thanks Maciej. I appreciate all the help folks.